# How to open app by using URL

Tags: android, deep-linking

I would like to open my app when user redirects an URL on the browser .

my URL is :

http://www.subdomain.Domain.com/mytransactions

inside `manifest.xml` I wrote this :

```
    <activity android:name="*.*.*.MyTransactions" >

        <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data
                android:host="www.domain.com"
                android:scheme="mytransactions"
                android:pathPrefix="/subdomain"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

but when I enter this URL on browser my app didn't launch.

Comment: Try to change `android:pathPrefix="/subdomain"` to `android:pathPrefix="/mytransactions"`.

Comment: i suggest you to use DeepLinks

Answer (score 0):

you need to do some changes in `<data>`

```
<data
    android:host="www.subdomain.Domain.com"
    android:pathPrefix="/mytransactions"
    android:scheme="http" />
```

problem with your code is that you have not defined `scheme`

Comment: and where is defined `mytransactions` ?

Comment: check updated answer, you need to provide it in `pathPrefix`, and also define `scheme` as `http`